# Get address from const

Tags: pointers, constants, nim-lang

From the [manual](http://nim-lang.org/manual.html#the-addr-operator):

> One can get the address of variables, but one can't use it on variables declared through let statements

I understand this is done to provide safety. Now, if i want to get the address from a const at all cost is there a workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consts really don't have an address, they may not even be stored anywhere at all. Let's look at this small program and see what happens in its intermediate C source code:

```
const x = 10
echo x
echo x + 1
```

The relevant C code looks like this:

```
STRING_LITERAL(TMP5, "10", 2);
STRING_LITERAL(TMP6, "11", 2);

NIM_EXTERNC N_NOINLINE(void, xInit)(void) {
    printf("%s\012", ((NimStringDesc*) &TMP5)? (((NimStringDesc*) &TMP5))->data:"nil");
    printf("%s\012", ((NimStringDesc*) &TMP6)? (((NimStringDesc*) &TMP6))->data:"nil");
}
```

So the calculation is actually done at compile time and the final strings for `echo` are stored in the program instead of the int `x`.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation. What if i want to retrieve the address from `let var` ?

Comment: @Arrrrrrr: That is exactly what I have been wondering for a while now, [leading to this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30132599/1804173).

Comment: Thanks for your notification @bluenote10