# Error: expression has no address

Tags: nim-lang

```
# lines 11-12:
proc last[T](ll: seq[T]): var T =
  return ll[high(ll)]

# line 118:
if last(formula)["state"] == c_empty:
```

Errors:

```
main.nim(118, 12) Info: template/generic instantiation from here    
main.nim(12, 12) Error: expression has no address
```

What the compiler wants?

Comment: Some time ago I had a related [question on whether parameters have an address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30132599/1804173) -- maybe it helps as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[]` does not return a var.

I don't think you need to annotate anything in this snippet with *var* though, since nothing is being mutated. Specify *var* at the call site if needed.

Try to submit compilable examples in the future if you can.

Comment: You can also index the last element by doing list[^1], and the element before that by doing list[^2]